# How to position div inside div inside another div and make them all 'resizable' and fit into any browser size?

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is to make a 'portfolio' page. But I want it to 'perfectly fit' in the size of the users browser (so that, no matter what size of the screen the user is equipped with, the content of the page is always fully visible). Therefore, the page should be "resizable" and always show 100% width and 100% height on widescreen, desktop, tablet or mobile phone... and according to the size of the screen the inner div's should stretch (or shrink) to fit nicely in the browser.

This is what I have made so far but it's not good.

http://jsfiddle.net/MPQXF/50/

And when I resize the height or width of the screen the white frame (together with the eight blue frames pops out of the 'upper' part of frame. And it doesn't stretch or fit as I change the browser's size.

Btw, the blue frames should represent a small images (let's say 250x250).

```
<section id="home">
    <div class="upper">
        <div class="frame" align="center">
            <div class="innerframe">
            </div>
            <div class="innerframe">
            </div>
            <div class="innerframe">
            </div>
            <div class="innerframe">
            </div>
            <div class="innerframe">
            </div>
            <div class="innerframe">
            </div>
            <div class="innerframe">
            </div>
            <div class="innerframe">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lower">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please explain how `.frame` should respond to resizing the window.  Right now, `.frame` has a fixed width and height.  What is the max height for `.frame`?  should it fit in the orange container?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, the .frame should fit in the very center of the orange container, and if possible it should resize according to the screen size. I added the fixed width and height because when I added the percentages it didn't show up at all. The same is valid for blue boxes that should fit inside the white one and also be resizable if possible. Than you!

Comment: That's not necessary but i want to be able to simply add more .innerframes if needed. So, for example, if I add the 9th blue boxs it can show up in the 3rd row below, or if the screen is wide the 9 blu boxes can be shown in the two rows only (5 and 4 in each row).

Comment: That sounds good but I am very new to web development so I don't know how to make it :(

Comment: Assuming that `.innerframe` is a 250x250 image, on a large screen, what is the maximum number of images that you want per row?  As the screen width gets smaller, do we shrink the images or put fewer per row? You need to be a lot more specific since this layout can be build in many ways.

Comment: max number of images per row is 4.  As the screen width gets smaller images should shrink if possible. Thank you.

Comment: If you have 14 images, that would mean 4 rows: 3 rows of 4 and 1 row of 2.  That means each row would have a height of 25% of the orange container, and the width of the images would adjust accordingly to maintain the square aspect ratio.

Comment: I can think of a way of doing it but it may require some jQuery/JavaScript to make it work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32484/discussion-between-c-felipe-and-marc-audet)

Answer (score 0):

You have specified widths as percentages for some divs and for a few of them the width and height is fixed in px. If you want the desired behavior make sure everything is in %s.

I have modified your CSS to make everything in %s. Pls test and see if it works fine. It does on the fiddle.

```
html, body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  height:100%;
}

section{
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
}

div{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.upper{
    background:orange;
}

.lower{
    background: green;
}

.frame{
  width: 35%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top:15%;
  height: 40%;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  position: relative;
  border-radius:3px;
}

.innerframe{
    width:20%;
    background:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:3px;
    height:42%;
}
```

Comment: When I added the %s blue boxes were not visible? Thank you for your participation!

Answer (score 0):

Use this css. your green div is also visible now

```
    html, body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  height:100%;
}

section{
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
}


.upper{
    background:orange;
}

.lower{
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
}

.frame{
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top:30px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  position: relative;
  border-radius:3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.innerframe{
    width:40px;
    background:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:3px;
    height:40px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I was looking for. Plus, my green div disappeared :(